# rsync using include-from to sync only specific files or directories

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

This seems like a really simple request but I've been banging my head against the wall with rsync for about an hour now so thought I'd just ask. I'm just trying to use rsync to whitelist a certain small set of files from a local directory to a remote one.

Let's imagine for now I just want to send only `*.ts` files in the root directory. So imagine this as the source structure:

```
/foo
  bar.ts
  baz.ts
  package.json
  node_modules/...
  other_dir/...
```

In this example, I just want to send `bar.ts` and `baz.ts`.

What I'm *trying* to do is just this:

`rsync --include-from include.txt foo remotehost:foo`

where `include.txt` contains only:

```
*.ts
```

When I try that, I get `skipping directory .` Why is that happening if I have an `include-from` list?

So then I tried using archive/recursive mode (but that's not what I want, because I'm just trying to specify a list... but let's try anyway):

`rsync -a --include-from include.txt foo remotehost:foo`

And that goes and just copies everything from `foo` and ignores the `include-from`.

So then I tried:

`rsync -a --exclude '*' --include-from include.txt foo remotehost:foo`

I thought the patterns were evaluated left to right, so I'd expect this to just include the files in my list, but it excludes them because they match the pattern '*'

Again, this seems like a super basic thing to do and I have no idea why it's so challenging to have rsync do this.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me start with the simplest solution, then go over why your attempts didn't do what you expect. Try this:

```
rsync foo/*.ts remotehost:foo
```

Note that the shell expands the wildcard before running `rsync`, so this is basically equivalent to:

```
rsync foo/bar.ts foo/baz.ts remotehost:foo
```

EDIT: after discussion in the comments, I think the root problem is that the rule name "*include"* is a bit misleading; it might be clearer to call them "*don't exclude*" rules, or even better "*don't exclude even if there's an exclude rule later in the filter list that says to*" (but those are verbose and not shell-script-syntax friendly, so "*exclude*" it is).

Put it this way: `-r` and `-a` tell `rsync` to transfer files/subfolders inside the source directory, "exclude" rules let you make exceptions to that (i.e. skip some of the items that would've been transferred), and "include" rules let you make exceptions to the exceptions (i.e. transfer items that a later "exclude" rule would've excluded).

Now, let's go over the commands that didn't work:

```
rsync --include-from include.txt foo remotehost:foo
```

The problem here is that you're telling it to sync a directory (foo), not the files *in* that directory. With the `-r` (or `-a`) option, it doesn't do that, so it just skips the directory. So, you add `-a`:

```
rsync -a --include-from include.txt foo remotehost:foo
```

...and now it sends everything, because you gave it a list of things to include, but didn't tell it to *exclude* anything. The default is to include things, and adding an explicit instruction to include specific things doesn't change that.

So you add an exclude instruction:

```
rsync -a --exclude '*' --include-from include.txt foo remotehost:foo
```

...but you put the exclude rule first, and it checks rules from left to right, acting on the first match. Since everything matches `*`, everything gets excluded, and the include rule from the file never gets applied.

You should be able to get it to work by putting the include rule first:

```
rsync -a --include-from include.txt --exclude '*' foo remotehost:foo
```

...but as I suggested at the beginning, it's easier to let a shell wildcard do the matching. Although you *would* need to use something like this if you were copying files from remote to local, because your local shell can't apply a remote wildcard.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response. The answers to examples 2 and 3 make sense to me, but I still think rsync's behaviour is super confusing for the first example. I'd expect to be able to omit `foo` entirely in the first example, just running `rsync --include-from include.txt remotehost:foo` and have that just use the include list. And I don't understand why the include list is completely ignored if the "directory but not its files" are specified. The include file is trying to specify the files! I'll also respond with my solution and mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @aardvarkk rsync filter rules tend to be very confusing if you don't have *exactly* the right mental model of them. The include/exclude rules are just filters that tell it to skip (or not skip) items that it would have transferred if the filters weren't there. If the source is a directory and neither `-r` or `-a` is specified, there are no valid candidate items to transfer, and a filter cannot change that. The `--files-from=FILE` option *does* add things to what'll be transferred, but it requires a list of specific filenames, not just patterns.

Comment: Put another way: if the source is a directory, but don't specify `-r` or `-a`, you're asking it to transfer the directory (*not* files inside it). So it doesn't even consider that foo/bar.ts and foo/baz.ts might be things it should notice the existence of, let alone transfer.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm seeing that now. My faulty assumption was that the set of files rsync would consider would be the *union* of `SRC` specified on the command line and the `--include` flag. The documentation (and the name of the flags) implied to me that the intention was "here are some files you should include, regardless of the command line". I guess I'm still confused about how `--include` is supposed to be used if you're generally having to pair it with `-a` and `--exclude`.

Comment: @aardvarkk Yep, `--include` is pretty useless if you don't pair it with some sort of exclude rule and `-r` or `-a`. Put it this way: `-r` and `-a` tell it to transfer files/subfolders inside the source directory, exclude rules let you make exceptions to that (i.e. skip some of the items that would've been transferred), and include rules let you make exceptions *to the exceptions* (i.e. transfer items that a later exclude rule would've excluded).

Comment: Great summary, thank you!

Comment: Note: technically, filter rules do mean something without `-r` or `-a` -- they can be used to exclude items explicitly listed for transfer. For example, if you run `rsync --exclude=bar.ts foo/bar.ts foo/baz.ts remotehost:foo`, it will only transfer baz.ts, not bar.ts.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Gordon Davisson for the detailed response.

I ended up going in the following direction, which behaved closer to what I expected and felt "elegant":

```
rsync -aF foo remotehost:foo
```

The `a` being the archive flag (to recursively process `foo`), and `F` indicating to rsync that it should look for a file named `.rsync-filter` in each directory it inspects.

Then my `.rsync-filter` file ended up specifying the include/exclude rules:

```
+ **/*.ts
- node_modules
```

I liked this solution because rsync already has an expected filename for this "filter", so I didn't need to make up (and specify) an arbitrary include/exclude filename. It's also a short, single-letter flag so the issued command is very readable.